# using memset to fill an array shows garbage

Tags: c++

I am stuck in a simple code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{

        int l;
        std::cin >> l;
        char leading[l];
        //std::fill_n(leading, l, '0');
        memset(leading, '0', sizeof(char)*l);
        std::cout << "->" << leading << "<- strlen=" << strlen(leading) << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the result of multiple runs(same problem with `std::fill_n`):

```
~/test$ g++ ptr.cpp 
~/test$ ./a.out 
3
->000*�<- strlen=6
~/test$ ./a.out 
7
->0000000<- strlen=7
~/test$ ./a.out 
6
->000000<- strlen=6
~/test$ ./a.out 
5
->00000<- strlen=6
~/test$ ./a.out 
2
->00@��<- strlen=6
```

Do I have to look for another job?

**UPDATE:**
As I will be using this array later in a `sprintf`, I don't want to use a null terminator. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: after memset do leading[l-1]='\0';

Comment: Your array is not nill-terminated. That's why you get garbage

Comment: Use std::string.

Comment: `std::string(l, '0')` is C++'s idiomatic way of making a string of `l` zero characters. Variable-length arrays are not standard in C++.

Comment: why am I getting -1 ? Is the question invalid?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the null-terminator? I don't understand why you think you should use them if you want to use sprintf later. `strlen` eiterates through until it finds a null terminator, so if there isn't one it walks beyond the end of the array (UB) until it finds one.

Comment: I didnt know about how `strlen` and `<<` behave wrt null terminator. Thanks guys.

Comment: And don't use sprintf. Use std::stringstream.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? This feels like part of a question. You tell use you want to use sprintf later. Do you want to have an arbitrary length string, either filled with the character `0`, or perhaps display a given length of 0s on screen, then change it later to show something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `strlen` and `operator<<(basic_ostream&, char*)` have the precondition that the pointer arguments point to a null terminated string of characters. Your array is not null terminated and therefore you violate those preconditions. As a result, the behaviour of your program is undefined.

---

> **UPDATE:** I don't with to use a null terminator. Is there a better alternative?

There is no need for an alternative for `strlen` since you already know the length: `l`.

For streaming a non-null-terminated character array, you can use an iterator:

```
std::ostream_iterator<char> it(std::cout);
std::copy(leading, std::end(leading), it);
```

---

PS.

> ```
> std::cin >> l;
> char leading[l];
> ```

This is ill-formed in C++. The size of an array must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your PS. Is there any probable bug that variable length array can cause?

Comment: @rahman the program won't work on other compilers that do not support the variable length array language extension that you use.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` is *not* the same as `'\0'` which is probably what you wanted. (No *encoding* system supported by C++ is allowed to set the character literal `'0'` to have the value 0.)

The behaviour on using `strlen` on this memory block will be undefined.

If you want to populate with the character 0, then remember to add a NUL-terminator to the memory block, in order for the C-type string functions (and `<<` for that matter) to be usable.

Comment: I do want to fill it with character `'0'`

Comment: Well you will need to append a NUL-terminator.

Comment: why? is there is a reason? coz I will later use this array in a sprintf, I dont want to include a null terminator.

Comment: Well, if you want `<<` and `strlen` to work, then you might want to consider it, yes ;-)

Comment: Please, note that OP is also using a variable-length array in a C++ program.

Answer (score 1):

Because both strlen and cout rely on a null terminator to indicate the end of the string